# Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V for copy and paste not working on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: shortcut-keys, 22.04, copy-and-paste

I am not able to use the shortcuts keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> for copy and paste, respectively, on my Ubuntu 22.04. However, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> works fine. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> also does not work.

Comment: In a terminal, you need to use shift+ctl+c  and v for cut and paste.  No idea why ctl+alt+t doesn't work,  unless you are not running the standard Gnome desktop.

Comment: If you are using another clipboard manager, for example CopyQ. You might check [this](https://copyq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/known-issues.html#known-issue-wayland)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in Ubuntu 22.04.

Some <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> functions worked, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> didn't work (not talking about the terminal, which has a different behavior with shortcuts). Both shortcuts, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> worked.

After several hours of unuseful googling and trying things (and multiple times coming to your question...), the solution was quite simple and weird:

I went to Configuration > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts (I use it in Spanish, [in this link shows how to do it](https://linuxhint.com/useful-ubuntu-keyboard-shortcuts/))

There were three custom shortcuts (although I customized none of them...), Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V and Ctrl+Z. When I disabled or deleted them, they started to work as expected.

Comment: Thanks!! After disable the Ctrl+C shortcut like you said worked for me on Debian 12 in Portuguese.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was [Gpaste](https://github.com/Keruspe/GPaste), stopped its tracking clipboard and solved

Answer (score 0):

For me, the default keyboard shortcuts was `SHIFT+CTRL+C` and `SHIFT+CTRL+V`, for terminal, I changed them in preferences.