# Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V for copy and paste not working on desktop (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: shortcut-keys, 22.04, copy-and-paste

If i use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> in, for example, Nautilus - it works fine (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> copies, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> pastes). Same for LibreOffice and other applications. But when I go to desktop - it doesn't work. Keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>C</kbd> do nothing, <kbd>V</kbd> opens a menu for searching a file on desktop. Ubuntu 22.04. Found nothing to deal with it in system settings and gnome-tweaks.
Similar problem here: [Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V for copy and paste not working on Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1439403/ctrlc-and-ctrlv-for-copy-and-paste-not-working-on-ubuntu-22-04)

Comment: For me right click - paste works. After that the same file can be pasted with Ctrl + V as well. However if I copy another file, still the previous file is pasted when I press Ctrl +V on the desktop. Right click + Paste will paste the new file and it also updates what Ctrl +V pastes. I wonder if noone has the same problem, or noone else needs this very basic functionality.